# the series $\sum\limits ^\infty _{k=1} \frac{1}{2^k+k-1}$ is convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

the series $\sum ^\infty _{k=1} \frac{1}{2^k+k-1}$ is convergent ?

My attempt:

$a_k=\frac{1}{2^k+k-1}$ then $a_{k+1}=\frac{1}{2^{k+1}+k+1-1}=\frac{1}{2^{k+1}+k}$

now $|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}|=\frac{2^k+k-1}{2^{k+1}+k}$ from here how to proceed  to next can you some one help me from here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sum ^\infty _{k=1} \frac{1}{2^k+k-1} \leq \sum ^\infty _{k=1} \frac{1}{2^k}$$

or following from your approach:

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{2^k+k-1}{2^{k+1}+k}=\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{1+\frac{k-1}{2^k}}{2+\frac{k}{2^k}}=?$$

Comment: ..thank you  and you used comparison test

Comment: ...how to find the value $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{2^k+k-1}{2^{k+1}+k}=\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{1+\frac{k-1}{2^k}}{2+\frac{k}{2^k}}=?$

Comment: .......is that value 1/2

Comment: yup, and we can make some conclusion from ratio test.

Comment: ...since the values is  less than 1 so the given series is convergent

Comment: yup, congratulations.